# Regex to remove all words starting with number

Tags: java, regex

I have following content stored in my Set:

```
...4tccs,4ug,5,50,6,6tccs,7,7ug,7west,8,8226,9,9fall,9west,a,aad,academic,account,acres,acresthis,acronyms,add,by,calendar,campus,campuses,can,capc,carey,catalog,catalogs,cd...
```

This is just a snippet of the overall data. Now I have to store this data into the file but I don't want to store all the words that starts with number.

So please suggest me the regex that could remove all the words like these.

Comment: !Character.isDigit(thestring.charAt(0)) where thestring is a string in the set

Comment: @AbuSulaiman, that's certainly more readable than the regex solutions. A programmer who comes along later will have no trouble understanding your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match:

```
"\\b\\d[^,]*(?:,|$)"
```

And replace with:

```
""
```

Comment: **Try with this string `9west,a,aad,5academic` output is `a,aad,` that is wrong.**

Answer (score 0):

Try below regex

```
(\\d+\\w*,)|(,\\d+\\w*$)
```

**Note** : The second regex will match the last word started by digit.

For e.g:

```
String s = "4tccs,4ug,5,50,6,6tccs,7,7ug,7west,8,8226,9,9fall,9west,a,aad,5academic";

System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\d+\\w*,)|(,\\d+\\w*$)", ""));
```

output:

```
a,aad
```

For more experiment have a look at [Online regex pattern checker](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CD9m1DxUrAqIbff2).